# Consecutive compilations fail: each time a different .sty file is not found

Tags: packages, miktex, compiling

I'm using pdflatex and MiKTeX to generate a report, with install packages on-the-fly turned on.

I've used a new package (hyperref) in it, but ever since it fails to compile. The message i get is:
`` File `<packagename_x>.sty' not found. ... ``, When I compile, it installs `<packagename_x>.sty`, but crashes at a different package `<packagename_y>.sty` which hasn't been installed yet. Then, if I compile again, it installs `<packagename_y>.sty`, but crashes at `<packagename_z>.sty`. And on and on it goes...

Does anyone seem to know what the problem is?

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: well it is as it is. It will stop when you have all packages. But I would simply install every package directly, if you have the disc space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - How would I go about doing that? I don't know which packages are needed in advance. Is that something I can find in the documentation of hyperref?

Comment: Go to the miktex console to the package tab, select everything uninstalled, click on install and get some coffee ...

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Just seems weird to me that MiKTex doesn't install dependables automatically. Thank you, @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: dependencies are complicated in latex, miktex can't maintain list of packages other packages need, so on-the-fly works one by one.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am new at MikTeX, but I choose the option to always install the package without asking, loaded my most complex document, and fired (and had a coffee). Sloooow but it managed to compile after installing around 100 packages. I suppose that in a couple week it will converge... (@UlrikeFischer :-))